# Multisite, second language Live Preview not working

Tags: localization, multi-site, live-preview

I have an English site - https://dev.mysite.com and a Japanese site - https://dev.mysite.com/jp.

Live preview works great for the English site, but the Japanese site has the following error:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://dev.mysite.com/admin/entries/home/3-home?site=japanese&draftId=90' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://dev.mysite.com/jp?x-craft-live-preview=dbSSGfPfBY&token=LTNsMdKk-I8XWFyoh7ozK2akf4Hy_oOO'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

I have the `Base URL` set within the Sites admin panel to https, as well as the `siteUrl` within `general.php`.

What am I missing?

Thank you!
Kelly

Answer (score 1):

Issue within the `.htaccess` file!

These lines were causing the redirect to https to malfunction:

```
# Remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```